# Compatibility Feasibility Speed and use of High Capacity MicroSd Card for adaptable swapping and linking apps?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, performance, adoptable-storage, benchmarks

I want purchase a new **high capacity (64GB or  128GB**)  high speed **(100Mbps 170Mbps 250 MBps)** MicroSdcard for **Swapping/Adoptable /linking apps** through Link2SD/ portable (adoptable) storage

so i want to confirm compatibility feasibility speed  performance my external sdcard **slot/tray/reader/chip/hardware** should have according to my device and  **Android lolipop 5.1.1** support.

High capacity MicroSd card comes with pre-formatted extfat file system but my mobile  manufacturer technical specification of mobile device says it supports up to 128gb and fat32 file system

There are many  available sdcards Micro
i want to know that type (SDHC SDXC) UHs speed Class (UHSI UHS II) Video Speed Class  (v10 v30 v60 V90)  and App performance class (A10)  Speed of (90 Mbps 100Mbps 170Mbps 250MBps) its confusing which  will  be compatible feasible and best for adaptable swap  and give optimum performance for the purpose.

secondly there is not use of  extra speed or video class card if Device or Android supports works on less speed.

Before purchasing to decide i want to confirm and check my device and understand clarify  following  questions and queries to decide  which card will be compatible for my android lolipop 5.1.1 OS and device:-

1. Can high capacity **exfat be forced**  to  used **(through mounting
   it inboot init**)  in android or phone through mount commands
   without damaging phone Android os  or SDcards protocols and will all
   apps/ os file manager support it if yes then

   ```
                                 *-kindly tell me commands for it.*
   ```
2. if not then can **high capacity card be formatted to Fat32** if yes
   then how can i format and will the card give the same performance
   speed performance as  in exfat to fat32 without damaging phone
   android OS and  SdCard

   ```
                                    *-kindly tell me commands for it*
   ```
3. In android Lolipop 5.1.1 file system (ext4) whats the **block size
   it use  to write or read on external sdcard**  is it 512 bytes/ 4096
   (4kB) /8096 (8KB) /512Kb /512bytes how to check  or it depends on 
   which  filesystem the sdcard is formatted with then  what block size
   it writes *individualy in filesystems  of  fat32, exfat, ntfs and
   ext4*

   - kindly tell me command  tools script or apps to check and confirm on
     my device
4. In android lolipop 5.1.1 file system of ext4 APPS and FILES  **how
   it write means sequentially or randomly**

   ```
            -kindly tell me command tools script or apps  to check and 
             confirm on my device
   ```
5. is there method or any adb shell android Command or script or apps
   of hardware info or bench marking apps through which we can check
   test to  know  device mobiles external Sdcard *SLOTS/READER/CHIP/HARDWARE** optimum hardware compatibility :-

   a) for **type** of device compatible microSD cards (SDHC / SDXC)

   ```
                    *- kindly tell me commands for testing it*
   ```

   b) Type of  **file system supported**  or mounted OR FORCED TO BE MOUNTED
     allowed/permitted  on externalsd card and can it be modified or changed

   ```
                             *- kindly tell me commands for testing it*
   ```

   c) maximum **Practical capacity** supported microSD in the device and can 
     it be forcebly be  extended ie. 128gb or  more we can force by 
     partitioning the card to multiple partitions or increasing the size

   ```
                             *- kindly tell me commands for testing it*
   ```

   d) **UHS speed Class** (UHSI UHS II) compatible

   ```
                            *- kindly tell me commands for testing it*
   ```

   e) **Video Speed Class**  (v10 v30 v60 V90) compatible

   ```
                            *- kindly tell me commands for testing it*
   ```

   f) **App performance class** (A1) compatible

   ```
                            *- kindly tell me commands for testing it*
   ```

   g) Maximum sequential read speed compatible (90 Mbps 100Mbps 170Mbps 
       250MBps)

   ```
                            *- kindly tell me commands for testing it*
   ```

   h) **minimum/Maximum sequential write** speed compatible

   ```
                            *- kindly tell me commands for testing it*
   ```

   i) **minimum/ Maximum random read/write  speed** compatible
                                 *- kindly tell me commands for testing it*
6. **for  suggestions  I have pre-tested through androbench app**

   a)  internal memory of my device through writing **64Mb** file  to /data/
      (ext4 partition mounted)  (64Mb file used for testing)

   ```
   sequential  read 128 MB/s

   sequential write 12 MB/s

   random read 10.93 Mb/s  2800.4 IOPS (4KB)

   random write 3.9 Mb p/s  996.31 IOPS (4KB)
   ```

   *is there any restriction in device or android should we need to match

   externalsd speed performance with internal sd  as we have     we can use

   external sdcard as internal either by swapping/adoptable /linking  or it 
   will work in more or less performance to*

   b) External memory of HP SHDHC Class 10 16GB (still i want to switch over to 
   high capacity card) of my device through writing 64Mb file  /external_sd/
   (fat32  partition mounted)(64 MB File)

   ```
   sequential  read 35.56 MB/s (printed 95MB/s)

   sequential write 8.6 MB/s

   random read 4.36 Mb/s  1117.58 IOPS (4KB)

   random write 0.53 Mb p/s  136.38 IOPS (4KB)
   ```

   Hp printed  95MB/s  but result is 35.5MB/s now its  device result,fat32
   file system result  or sdcard  performance result don't know how to
   differentiate  it .

   ```
                       *- kindly tell me commands for testing it*
   ```

**how to find device external mircro sdcard slot/chip/hardware/reader speed and other  information asked above**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your device is very old, which most likely means that it does not have exfat support.

Compatibility should not be a problem, as every card and reader are usually compatible with each other, as long as SDXC cards are supported by your device.

And for adoptable storage the bulk transfer speed is not that important (as long as you don't record videos or often copy/download large files). I would focus on A1/A2 rating which is designed to measure application usage (randomly reading/writing a number of small files).

I would also focus on reliability because if the sd-card dies all data on your device will be non-accessible/gone.

Anyway in your old device the sd-card will not work very fast. Even in modern devices the sd-card reader is not able to make use of the modern very fast transfer modes.

In general the micro-sd card is way slower (independent what card you use) than the internal flash, because the integrated card reader is slow.

Comment: in brief  how can we check test and see  the integrated card reader specification of the devices through any app benchmarking tool or any command

Comment: how can we precheck  reliability of Externalsd card. and integrated card reader

Comment: @Androidquery SD-card reader capabilities: read the technical specification of the phone and if you don't find there something on the reader you can't (only guess it from the transfer speed you measure). Anyway just assume the worst so you don't get disappointed. Also the reliability can't be really checked. Buy branded product of a brand that also produces flash memory (like e.g. SanDisk, Samsung, ..). And make sure to check if you did not bought a forged product (test the disk using `h2testw` or a similar tool if it really has the claimed capacity).

Comment: robert as a2 feature is available with  UHSII or UHSIII cards integrated reader detect  (on low speed low performance ) or not because they are expensive and if  dosnt get detected even then it will be wastage  on old phones as  some site i readed  that it needs some special voltage of 3.99 thats what i want to know that if purchase some card and later on it didnt detetcted then it will be problem

Comment: currently no known UHS-II smartphones or tablets. the Galaxy S10 is UHS-I only. you are fine with any Class 10 SDXC