# For Adoptable storage Fast random WRITE speed or fast random READ average good speed values?

Tags: external-sd, internal-sd, adoptable-storage, benchmarks

For Adoptable storage Fast random  WRITE speed or fast random READ average  good speed values?

To move and use apps on its microSD Card (using microsd card as adaptable storage as internal memory) in android 6.0 marshmallow formatting  SD as internal  my droid suggests I use a "fast" SD card.

https://www.cameramemoryspeed.com/sd-memory-card-faq/fastest-memory-card/
Ranks SD Cards by WRITE Speed and READ Speed. Interestingly, the same chips seldom appear in both lists. If I want to use my SD Card to store and run apps, is fast random WRITE speed or is fast random READ speed the most important quality to look for. As in many card random read speed is 230mbps and random write speed is 3 or 5 mobs there are some cards in which both random read write speed is  90mbps 100mbps Approx. So what's the internal storage random read write speed standard average value as apps read more than write.

In android perspective using SD card as adaptable internal storage what is  The important thing for best performance in micro sd card must be high IOPS, high 4k read/write values an average value the apps use to read and write on micro sd card .

But what is queue depth (QD) 1..32? For example random read 4k-QD1, random read 4k-QD32, random write 4k-QD1, random read 4k-QD32... Which values of QD are important for  android adoptable storage.

I just found another  old benchmark link

to find hdparm dd Linux benchmarking but its with old model 16gb 32 GB cards

https://www.pidramble.com/wiki/benchmarks/microsd-cards

https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2019/raspberry-pi-microsd-card-performance-comparison-2019

I am planning for 128 GB UHS II v30 a2 cards  do any can share  any benchmark results for new microsd card for android adoptable app perspective for cards

Is there any command or benchmark  app in android through which we can benchmark or test the internal memory storage speed and match same or higher value random read and write speed  external microsd card speed for making it compatible matching speed of internal memory. Kindly share the apps I founded androbench, SD speed test but both test external SD card not internal

Comment: For adoptable storage bulk read/write benchmarks are not so important. More important are IOPS and random read/write speed of small data blocks. And of course reliability - for adoptable storage I would never use a no-name product.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220035/218526